# How to update points by adding previous points and current points

Tags: php, mysql

How do I update my php/mysql by adding the previous vote and new vote
for example, in mysql. the vote point is 25. when I entered again with 25points. it became 50points. this is the scenario. I have table name"subj_eva" with coloumn of id, facultyname and totalvotes. how do I update my totalvotes by adding the old points and new points?

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password="password"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="ramon_pascual"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="subj_eva"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Get values from form 
$profname=$_POST['profname'];
$votecount=$_POST['votecount'];
$subj=$_POST['subject'];


// Insert data into mysql 
$sql = "UPDATE $tbl_name SET facultyname='$profname', totalvotes='$votecount', subjects='$subj'";

$result=mysql_query($sql);

// if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful". 
if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='indextest.php'>Back to main page</a>";
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}
?> 

<?php 
// close connection 
mysql_close();


?>
```

and this is my html code

```
<html>
<head><title> index test</title></head>
<body>

<table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
<tr>
<td><form name="form1" method="post" action="welcome.php">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3">
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><strong>Insert Data Into mySQL Database </strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="71">Professor Name</td>
<td width="6">:</td>
<td width="301"><input name="profname" type="text" id="profname"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>vote count</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="votecount" type="text" id="votecount"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>subject</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="subject" type="text" id="subject"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3" align="center"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions; use PDO / MySQLi instead. Plus, your HTML codes are very old style; use CSS instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your query to add the new value to the current value. I recommend converting votecount to an integer beforehand.

```
$votecount = intval($votecount);
$sql = "UPDATE $tbl_name SET facultyname='$profname', totalvotes=totalvotes + $votecount, subjects='$subj'";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:
`$sql = "UPDATE $tbl_name SET facultyname='$profname', totalvotes=totalvotes + '$votecount', subjects='$subj'";`

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand what you want, but is always use in the transmission function mysql_real_escape_string() database any string variables! Otherwise possible Mysql injections. And in double quotes variables highlight the brackets {}, otherwise the function will give the database is not the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$votecount=$_POST['votecount'];

$getprevious =mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from $tbl_name order by id desc"));

$previouspoint= $getprevious[0]['totalvotes'];

$votecount = intval($previouspoint) + intval($votecount);

$sql = "UPDATE $tbl_name SET facultyname='$profname', totalvotes='$votecount', subjects='$subj'";

$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

try using like this

```
$query="update table_name set 'totalvotes'=(select `totalvotes` from `table_name` where id='".$id."')+'".$current_count."' where id='".$id."' ";
```